# How to set up QoS VoIP priority on linux

Tags: linux, proxy, voip, qos

I am configuring a small network and my idea is to use a linux server as a proxy it will be serving local services to the clients and it will have also a squid server as a caching server for speeding up the network.

Web traffic is important and the mail, etc. The faster the better. But during VoIP conversations bad quality will be result in a bad conversation. I would like to set up a total priority to VoIP connections. My main target no VoIP conversation with low quality because a lack of bandwidth.

Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at linux QoS mechanism, i suggest you investigate HFSC rather than HTB.

there are some ready-made scripts like [this](https://github.com/automatthias/hfsc/blob/master/hfsc) one and few linked in the references that you can try.

Comment: Thank you! Thanks to your comment I am now on the track I am looking into this sites, just in case could be useful for more people:

http://automatthias.wordpress.com/2006/06/30/hfsc-and-voip/
https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=33896
http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/QoS+Linux+with+HFSC

If you want some theory:

http://linux-ip.net/articles/hfsc.en/